# Introduction to Metamathematics (Kleene): I need accompanying exercises

Tags: logic, self-learning, foundations

I am about to start self-studying from this book and I hadn't realized it contains no exercises.

I would be thankful if someone were to link me to some site that has exercises appropriate for the book, or even another textbook with good exercises that are similar to those that might theoretically have been included in the book.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Kleene's book? There are more recent books that (in my opinion) are better . . .

Comment: Someone recommended it to me. What would you suggest?

Comment: Consider **Ch.VIII Formal Number Theory**, page 181-on. The proof of most of the formulae (from #100 to #180) is only hinted: a good exercise can be to provide the fully detailed derivations.